# Latidude and Longitude are incorrect first time app is launched ios

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, cllocation, openweathermap

I am using CLLocationManager to get the user's current location. I need the user's current location because I am using the Open Weather Api to display the weather data wherever the user is. My problem is that the first time I open the app the lat and long value are 0, 0. But then if I run the app again it works fine. So only on the first launch of the app incorrect lat and long values are used. I do all my set up in viewDiDLoad, here is the code...

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    [self->locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Is it something to do with getting the lat and long in the view controller instead of App Delegate?

Here is how I am getting the location values:

```
locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude
```

Comment: The code does not show how you obtain and process the location value. I suggest you share this as well. Also, is it simulator or real device?

Comment: Okay posting that code now. And I am using an actual device. This error occurs on both simulator and device though.

Comment: Are you saying that these two lines follow the previous code lines within the same block/method?

Comment: No these are what I pass in to the method that makes the http request to the open weather api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because when you launch your app first time **Location manager** asks for user permission to access current location and when user allows - It takes little time in process of fetching current location and you're accessing coordinates before completion of that process.

When you launch your app again **Location manager** detects that you already gave the permission so it gives you current location coordinate very quickly.

So the solution is - you've to wait until it completes location update opt. You can put some kinda delay there using **dispatch** OR can use Location manager delegate method **didUpdateUserLocation** OR if your UIViewController isn't the initial view controller - in this case you should implement this process in AppDelegate, use your code in **didFinishLaunching**, so when you'll open your view controller (whatever navigation flow you're using) location details will be there cause in meantime location manager will track your location.

Hope it'll help you!

Comment: Thank you it worked for me. What I did was in NSUserDefaults I checked if this is the first time the user is launching the app and if it was I set a boolean to true. And then in the view controller I checked the value of the boolean and if it was true I used dispatched to execute the http request after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You should check `horizontalAccuracy` of the `CLLocation` object for a negative value and do not use the lat/lon value if that is the case. It is highly likely that when you see the lat/lon values are 0/0, the GPS hasn't secured a location lock.

Comment: Horizontal accuracy is 65. What should I do? Should i add a completion handler and only display weather once lat and long are retrieved?

Comment: You should check the weather service's granularity and compare it with the GPS' horizontal accuracy.